# Need Help for Developing XML file based Android App with Editable Item List

Tags: android

I am currently working on an Android Application which shows Data from XML file and can be also edited.

This app parses XML document and displays contents of nodes in List of EditText Views, XML file contains nodes of items with child nodes as follows

- Item Image Path
- Item Name
- Item Price

Later i want to edit this information in Android app and update XML with this newly edited data.

**What I have tried :**

1. Used RecyclerView but this doesn't allowed to get text from EditText which are invisible in view.
2. Also used ListView but it doesn't allowed to edit text of EditText. When tried to edit focus goes somewhere else.

   (XML Parsing and writing XML part is done.)

Can anyone tell me number of possible ways to do that.(I am Rookie in Android Development).[****App Screenshot****](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxUZs.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely get the entered text in the edit text,you can use the OnFocusChangeListener to the edit text and in listview u need to add this xml attribute :

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

and in manifest add this:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".youractivity"
          .....
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
```

Comment: i tried your solution but it didn't worked, focus still went somewhere else when clicked on EditText view

Comment: add this in manifest windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: Yeah that worked.. Thank You Avinash !!

Comment: listView.getChildAt(4) works fine as 5 items are visible in view at a time, but when i use listView.getChildAt(5) null object reference occurred.

Comment: i need to see ur adapter code for being able to tell u what exactly is happening,plzz post a different question for that

Comment: reached question limit :p

Comment: how many list items are there in total??

Comment: there are 10 items

Comment: Hey i got it... now i am updating the listArray of according to the change in EditText and then at the time of writing XML file i am getting the content from this listArray